# how to verifay mocked method with parameters

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am testing repository method.
I add stub for api call

```
when(appApiService.changeCardStatus(
            cardId, ChangeCardStatusRequest(status: CARD_STATUS_ELIGIBLE)))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => HttpResponse(
            true,
            Response(
                requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
                statusCode: successStatusCode,
                data: true)));
```

then i call repo method `await repositoryImpl.doEligibleCard(cardId: cardId, isEligible: isEligible);` my api method should called. then i verify

```
verify(appApiService.changeCardStatus(
        cardId, ChangeCardStatusRequest(status: CARD_STATUS_ELIGIBLE)));
```

But, my test feiled

```
package:test_api                                                                              fail
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 714:7                                                           _VerifyCall._checkWith
package:mockito/src/mock.dart 991:18                                                          _makeVerify.<fn>
test/unit/repository_test/my_cards_repository_impl/my_cards_repository_impl_test.dart 278:11  main.<fn>

No matching calls. All calls: MockAppApiServiceTest.changeCardStatus('55', Instance of 'ChangeCardStatusRequest')
(If you called `verify(...).called(0);`, please instead use `verifyNever(...);`.)
```

Failed, because i use ChangeCardStatusRequest as a parameter to api method and that is why verify not see api call.So how to verify method with class parameter like `ChangeCardStatusRequest`?

my api method

```
 @POST('/cards/{cardId}/status')
  Future<HttpResponse> changeCardStatus(
      @Path("cardId") String cardId, @Body() ChangeCardStatusRequest changeCardStatusRequest);
```

my repository method

```
@override
  Future<DataState<bool>> doEligibleCard({required String cardId, required bool isEligible}) async {
    return await doSafeApiCall(
        () async => await _appApiService.changeCardStatus(
            cardId,
            ChangeCardStatusRequest(
                status: isEligible ? CARD_STATUS_ELIGIBLE : CARD_STATUS_INELIGIBLE)),
        (responseData) => isEligible);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make ChangeCardStatusRequest extends Equtable to be able to compare

Also a side note, to use `when` without attaching it to specific parameters only,pass `any()` instead,
so instead of

```
when(appApiService.changeCardStatus(
            cardId, ChangeCardStatusRequest(status: CARD_STATUS_ELIGIBLE)))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => HttpResponse(
            true,
            Response(
                requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
                statusCode: successStatusCode,
                data: true)));
```

it becomes

```
when(appApiService.changeCardStatus(
            any(), any()))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => HttpResponse(
            true,
            Response(
                requestOptions: RequestOptions(path: ''),
                statusCode: successStatusCode,
                data: true)));
```

but it only works by adding In test setUpAll this line for custom classes

```
registerFallbackValue(ChangeCardStatusRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an argument matcher like [argThat](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/argThat.html) here, and also you need to give the expected number of calls with [called](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/VerificationResult/called.html).

Possibly like this:

```
verify(appApiService.changeCardStatus(
    cardId, 
    argThat((request) => request.status == CARD_STATUS_ELIGIBLE))).called(1);
```

If the method you are verifying has non-nullable arguments, you need to override it in you Mock class, as described here:

[Manually override a method with a non-nullable parameter type.](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md#manually-override-a-method-with-a-non-nullable-parameter-type)

In your case this might look like:

```
class MockApiService extends Mock implements ApiService {
  @override
  void changeCardStatus(int? cardID, ChangeCardStatusRequest? request) =>
    super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#changeCardStatus, [cardID, request]));
}
```

Comment: argThat()  - nullable, but ChangeCardStatusRequest not nullable(

Comment: @RootRoot I have updated my answer. Pls have a look